# Right-align and center in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I frequently use tables containing numbers that must be right-aligned so that the digits in the ones/tens/hundreds/thousands places line up.  Like this:

```
    2,343
1,000,000
       43
   43,394
  232,111
```

Column headers in these tables are centered. When the table columns are wide, it doesn't look great:

```
         Column 1                    Column 2
===========================|===========================
                     2,343 |                        32     
                        43 |                    44,432
                12,243,394 |                        23 
                   232,111 |                     4,432
```

Is there a way using javascript, jQuery or CSS to center the numbers based on the widest number, but keep the right justification? The desired end result would be like this:

```
         Column 1                    Column 2
===========================|===========================
             2,343         |              32     
                43         |          44,432
        12,243,394         |              23 
           232,111         |           4,432
```

I know I could set td padding globally, but I am looking for a dynamic solution that will adapt to different tables, even with different column width and number width.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

For a number column you want to align "centered right", use three columns, where the left and right column are set to 50%.

The numbers are placed in the middle column. Since no width is set for this column, it gets the smallest possible width, which is the width of the widest number. This width is taken from the left and right column in equal parts.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <colgroup><col width="50%"><col><col width="50%"></colgroup>
  <thead style="text-align:center;">
    <tr><td colspan="3"> /* any optional head line */ </td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="text-align:right;">
    <tr><td></td><td>123,456,789</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>456,789</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>789</td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It works fine as long as all numbers in a column have the same number of decimal places. If required, you can use the left column to align signs and the right column to display footnotes (left-aligned) without disturbing the alignment.

For more than one number column use following rule, where n is the number of number columns and x_i is half of the desired width of the i-th number column and sum(x_i)=100:

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="x_i %"><col><col width="x_i %"> // for each number column
  </colgroup>
  <thead style="text-align:center;">
    <tr><td colspan="3*n"> /* table head line */ </td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"> /* column head line */ </td></tr> // for each number column
  </thead>
  <tbody style="text-align:right;">
    <tr>
      <td></td><td> /* number */ </td><td></td> // for each number column
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is very clever—I have to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious trick would be to use additional table cells. I.e.

```
         Column 1                   Column 2
===========================|===========================
      .      2,343 .       |        .     32 .    
      .         43 .       |        . 44,432 .
      . 12,243,394 .       |        .     23 .
      .    232,111 .       |        .  4,432 .
```

Where the `.` indicate invisible table borders with automatic width.

Comment: To properly align the header, the `colspan="3"` attribute should be set on the `<th>` (table header cells).

Comment: My goal for this is to be easy and remain semantic, so I wouldn't want  to have to add a ton of custom cells "manually". These tables are being edited by non-programmers in TinyMCE.

Comment: So the numbers are not coming from a backend data source like a database or something? You only have the pure HTML and are not generating it?

Comment: Hard to do without extra elements and for dynamic width. You could set a left and right padding for the `td` tags, and have a javascript automatically decrease it when a horizontal scrollbar is visible. Wrapping the text in a `span` with a `min-width:10em; text-alignment:right` comes to my mind, but probably will not work with TinyMCE either.

Comment: nice try but bad idea i have 7 cells of data that need to be center right aligned with 1400 rows, that would result in 3 times the number of empty cells, page rendering is gonna be messed up big time, isnt there a workaround for this

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer a different answer than changing the markup to meet your needs:

Use jQuery's width() function and iterate through the column headers, checking/storing their widths. Then either add a predefined class (with padding) or change the TD padding of each cell in the column.

Something along the lines of this:

```
jQuery("thead td").each(function(columnIndex)
{
    var width=jQuery(this).width();

    jQuery(":not(thead) > tr").each(function()
    {                               
        jQuery(this).find("td").eq(columnIndex).css("padding-right",width/2);
    });
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5rw4/3/

Comment: This does not factor in different text width in different cells. The right padding has to vary per column based on the widest piece of text. In other words, right padding needs to be `(columnWidth - widestText)/2`

Answer (score 0):

All right, I went through some of the answers and find it hard to accept the idea of adding extra columns that serve absolutely no purpose. I will suggest a better method that involves adding non breaking spaces at the start of each character and center aligning everything without adding extra columns
Use the function below to pad Strings with an extra character sequence at the start

```
function padString(pad, str, leftPadded) {
    if (str === undefined) return pad;
    if (leftPadded) {
        return (pad + str).slice(-pad.length);
    } else {
        return (str + pad).substring(0, pad.length);
    }
}

var coin, newRow, newCell, value, newText
var spaces = new Array(4).fill('\u00A0').join('')
for(let i = 0; i < 1400; i++){
// Insert a row in the table at row index 0
    newRow = tbody.insertRow(i);

  // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell.className = 'rank'

    value = padString(spaces,''+ (i + 1) ,true)
  // Append a text node to the cell
    newText = document.createTextNode(value);
    newCell.appendChild(newText);   
}
```

All columns are center aligned but with the extra non breaking space in front of each item, they all become center right aligned

Comment: The serious limitation in this approach is that fonts have to be mono spaced, anyone else know a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the **`td`** text into a **`<span>`** and then find the **`max-width`** using **`Math.max.apply(null, Array)`** and apply some css rules into the span like below

```js
$("td").wrapInner("<span></span>");
var arr = [];
var columns = $("table").find("tr")[0].cells.length;
var rows = $("table").find("tr").length - 1;
for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= rows; j++) {
    arr.push($('table tr:eq("' + j + '") td:eq("' + i + '") span').outerWidth());
  }
  //console.log(arr);
  //console.log(Math.max.apply(null, arr));
  $('table tr').find('td:eq("' + i + '") span').css('width', Math.max.apply(null, arr))
  arr = [];
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px Monospace;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 6px;
}

td span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2,343</td>
    <td>32</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>44,432</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12,243,394</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>232,111</td>
    <td>4,432</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```